# android- handler.postDelayed how does it achieve the Delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading

for any task that had to be delayed I had been using: `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r,Long Delay)` , but I just recently came across the documentation and it says this:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached. The time-base is SystemClock.uptimeMillis(). Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay to execution.

I have two confusions in this:

1. Is the delay achieved by adding the `Runnable` to the `MessageQueue`
   after a specified delay of time?

   Or,
2. Is the `Runnable` added immediately and the function is delayed for
   a specified time. If this is so there must be mechanism that the
   Runnable is dequeued and put somewhere else so that other items in
   the queue can be processed. How is the Runnable delayed and how is
   the `MessageQueue` maintained during this delay?

Comment: Just a guess: 2. When the runnable gets to the front of the queue its execution time is evaluated, if its in the future its posted back to the back of the queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runnable is immediately added to the message queue which can be seen in source code of the [handler class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.3.5_r1/core/java/android/os/Handler.java) `postDelayed->sendMessageDelayed->sendMessageAtTime`

```
public boolean sendMessageAtTime(Message msg, long uptimeMillis)
{
    boolean sent = false;
    MessageQueue queue = mQueue;
    if (queue != null) {
        msg.target = this;
        sent = queue.enqueueMessage(msg, uptimeMillis);
    }
    else {
        RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException(
            this + " sendMessageAtTime() called with no mQueue");
        Log.w("Looper", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return sent;
}
```

`queue.enqueueMessage` runs a  `for (;;)` to delay the callback.
In this continuous loop message's time is checked for execution. you can see this in the source [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java)

Comment: how is the queue structured while the job is delayed?

Comment: Queue is structured as a linked list, which then iterated and checked with `when` (contains time to be executed) variable in `Message` object. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/os/Message.java

Answer (score 2):

The structure we call `Handler` runs with a `Looper` which contains a `MessageQueue` inside it. A call to `Handler.post(runnable)` creates a new message for `MessageQueue` and puts it at the last of the queue, where its time is set as `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`. `Looper` always loops for checking messages and if there is a message and the target time has been passed, it executes the `Runnable` inside it.

To clarify:

`Handler.post(runnable)` sends a message with `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` where on the next check, the new `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` becomes bigger than the message's execution time, allowing the `Looper` to fetch the runnable and execute it.

Now, if you use `Handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay)` it posts the message with `SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay` where the delay is in milliseconds, which we will call `messageTime` for now. What does the looper do? It checks the message, if `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` is smaller than `messageTime`, it skips the execution. Looper always loops, so there becomes a time where `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` actually becomes bigger than `messageTime` where the runnable becomes eligible for execution.

Unless you call `Handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(runnable)`, the calls are always put to the bottom of the queue, not the top.

Finalize:

`Handler.post(runnable)` --> `messageTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`

`Handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay)` --> `messageTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay`.

Looper executes the runnables where `SystemClock.uptimeMillis() >= messageTime`. That's the gist of it.

Comment: is the message with `SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay` put at the end of the queue?